# Apply Ordinal Encoding to an entire column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm working with a dataset of movies to run a regression and predict the gross.
But because some columns have String values, I'm doing an Ordinal Encoding before I do the split and run the regression.
One example is the column containing the movie titles(shown below):

```
Series_Title
1     The Shawshank Redemption
2     The Godfather
3     The Dark Knight
...
1001  The 39 Steps
```

Here's my code to run Ordinal Encoding on these first 3 movies:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['The Shawshank Redemption','The Godfather','The Dark Knight']})
df2['title'] = df1.Series_Title.astype("category").cat.codes
df2

OUTPUT:
0   875
1   786
2   766
```

Since the Series_Title column has 1,000 values, how can I apply Ordinal Encoding to the entire Series_Title column?

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
data = {'col': {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4:'A'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`:

```
    col
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   A
```

**Ordinal Encoding**

```
df['col'] = pd.factorize(df['col'])[0]
```

result(`df`)

```
    col
1   0
2   1
3   2
4   0
```